# What are different ways to make system level changes in Android?

Tags: android, root

**Requirements** :

1. Need to change some system files
2. Install one application as system
   app

I know that above two requirements need rooted device, but device is not of well-known company so there is no support available from CWM, TWRP or any other.

---

Yet I've some how managed to get some tools and files to install android 5.1 from device manufacturer as below,

1. Intel's Platform Flash [Tool](https://01.org/android-ia/downloads/intel-platform-flash-tool-lite)
2. Also all necessary files such as
   recovery.img(stalk-read only permission), system.img etc.

Now what I've think of solution so far is to unpack and repack system.img and replace new system.img with existing one and install with Intel's Platform Flash Tool, [XDA reference-1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1588461).

Unpack:

1. mkdir sys
2. ./simg2img system.img sys.raw
3. sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop sys.raw sys/

Repack:

1. sudo ./make_ext4fs -s -l 512M -a system new.img sys/
2. sudo umount sys
3. rm -fr sys

also calculated size = "Block count" * "Block size", [XDA reference-2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1588461&page=3)

And after creating sucessully system.img and also installation is also complete with Intel's Platform Flash Tool, bur is not able to boot and stuck at loading screen.

---

Solutions that I can think of:

1. Is there something that I'm missing in above method of unpack/repack method of system.img?
2. I've Intel's Platform Flash Tool, so is there any way to put my changes during installation of android OS?
3. I've also recovery.img, is it possible to modify this and create custom recovery.img and give read and write permission to system files?
4. Are there any other solutions which meets my requirements?

Comment: Hi Chitrang, did you ever manage to solve this?
I'm in a similar situation with an unknown band using an Intel processor on 5.1.0. I can create the System.img, but when the tablet is starting again it's stuck on the Intel logo. 

When looking on the guide it looks like it's for older Android versions.

I would have a look here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2600364


General comments (I think):
The file size you got seems quite small, ours is about  ~1.3gig.
I also think you're missing the file_contexts necessary for SELinux (look in root of original rom)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ls -l sys.raw
```

copy its filesize

then:

```
sudo ./make_ext4fs -s -l <size of sys.raw> -a system new.img sys/
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : go to the website << source.android.com >> and follow the tutorial to download and build the source code of the version of the android OS you're interested in making corresponding modifications.

Step 2 : Download the book << embedded android >> and follow the guide starting at page 148 of the book under " Adding an App " to solve your requirement 2.

Step 3 : Browse the rest of the book to solve your requirement 1.

Enjoy! Cheers!